# Linking HTML to deleted CSS file behaves as if the file is still there

Tags: html, css, file

First things first, I'm fairly new to this and could be making a silly mistake.

I'm running apache2 on my raspberry pi. I had a link in my HTML document to a CSS document with a background picture in it. After some trouble making any changes to the contents displayed, I eventually ended up erasing all the content in CSS document and then deleting it completely. Yet the image still displays. When I comment out the link to the (now removed) CSS document, the image that it was instructing the browser to display disappears.

I tried restarting the system but the "ghost file" is still working.
I'm using nano for the editing if that means anything.

The HTML-CSS link looks like
`<link href="/css/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">`
Running `ls` while in /var/www/html/css returns nothing.

Please help!

Comment: I would guess that your browser is caching the GET request... try hard-reloading? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache)

Comment: Thanks much! I didn't know about hard-reloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
> -Hold the Ctrl key and press the F5 key.
> -Hold the ⇧ Shift key and click the Reload button on the navigation toolbar.
> -Hold the Ctrl key and click the Reload button on the navigation toolbar.
> -Hold the ⇧ Shift key and press the F5 key.
```

These are for bypassing your cache on your browser. Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cache, i have this issue when removing things from my css, it acts as if it's still there but once you clear your cache it will update.

I use Chrome if you don't know how to clear go to Settings, type cache in the search bar and click clear browsing history and check the cahced images and files box, i clear it for the whole of time as i constantly work on different projects hope this helps :)